# Why is my ListAdapter not showing any data?

Tags: java, android, json, listadapter, simpleadapter

I am trying to fill a View with a list of items from a JSON data source. 
I can't seem to make the adapter show the JSON data in my list. This is what I have done so far.

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.todoapp.android.json;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "items";
    private static final String TAG_INDEX = "index";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray items = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            String jsonStr = "{\"items\":[{\"index\":1,\"name\":\"Bobby\",\"events\":[{\"index\":19,\"email\":\"louis@hardy.eg\"},{\"index\":13,\"email\":\"cynthia@mills.mc\"},{\"index\":0,\"email\":\"leo@graham.kp\"}]}]}";

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                        //String id = c.getString(TAG_INDEX);
                        //String index = c.getString(TAG_INDEX);
                        String index = String.valueOf(c.getInt(TAG_INDEX));
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_INDEX, index);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("foo", "error", e);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_INDEX, TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.index,
                    R.id.name });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

## list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/index"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Email label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />



</LinearLayout>
```

## content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.todoapp.android.json.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The only thing i get in logcat is in "Verbose" mode is

```
12-15 12:13:58.152 18184-18184/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-15 12:13:58.235 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.todoapp.android.json themeResourceId=2131230766
12-15 12:13:58.245 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
12-15 12:13:58.252 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
12-15 12:13:58.252 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
12-15 12:13:58.351 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
12-15 12:13:58.353 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
12-15 12:13:58.353 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
12-15 12:13:58.376 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: false
12-15 12:13:58.377 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK PROCESS DONE ! STATUS (0/0x2002)
12-15 12:13:58.377 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json W/[DRVB]: sec_drv_base_check: DRVB PROCESS STATUS = 0x2002
12-15 12:13:58.381 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-15 12:13:58.382 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-15 12:13:58.387 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-15 12:13:58.389 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/[MALI][Gralloc]: dlopen libsec_mem.so fail
12-15 12:13:58.399 18184-18220/com.todoapp.android.json D/Response:: > {"items":[{"index":1,"name":"Bobby","events":[{"index":19,"email":"louis@hardy.eg"},{"index":13,"email":"cynthia@mills.mc"},{"index":0,"email":"leo@graham.kp"}]}]}
12-15 12:13:58.453 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
12-15 12:13:58.453 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
12-15 12:13:58.453 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
12-15 12:13:58.504 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
12-15 12:13:58.504 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
12-15 12:13:58.504 18184-18214/com.todoapp.android.json I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
12-15 12:13:58.596 18184-18184/com.todoapp.android.json I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f8bfa22 time:6011123
```

`

The app on the physical phone starts alright but then is blank. Any pointers? My json file looks like this:

## json data

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "index": 1,
            "name": "Bobby",
            "events": [
                {
                    "index": 19,
                    "email": "louis@hardy.eg"
                },
                {
                    "index": 13,
                    "email": "cynthia@mills.mc"
                },
                {
                    "index": 0,
                    "email": "leo@graham.kp"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: make sure you have added correct permissions.

Comment: @KaranMer the only permssion i have is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` which i think is irrelevant anyway cause i'm not getting the json from the internet. what other permission could i possibly need?

Comment: post activity_main.xml

Comment: You should change the logging of your JSON exception to Log.e("Some String", e.getMessage, e); That should show you if the parsing is correct.

The next step is to use the debugger to check the content of contact list before you pass it to the adapter. You need to find out if the error is in converting the json or in filling the list.

Comment: set adapter first and then notify your adapter after filling arraylist

Comment: just log contactList on post execute and check whether data has got added to it or it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the `JSON` you posted:

```
private static final String TAG_ITEM = "item";
```

should be

```
private static final String TAG_ITEM = "items";
```

`index` is an `int` not a `String`, and this line

`String index = c.getString(TAG_INDEX);`

is mostly making the parsing failing. Change it with

`String index = String.valueOf(c.getInt(TAG_INDEX));`

Comment: anything on the logcat ? Can you post your activity's layout ?

Comment: try passing `R.layout.content_main` to setContentVIew

Comment: that makes the whole screen go blank.

Comment: `TAG_ITEM = "item";` should be `TAG_ITEM = "items";`. Notice the plural in the second one\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/857853/zharf helped me fix my json data. it's working now :). thanks @Blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be due to JSONException.

Try with following codes and run

```
 String jsonString = "{\\n\\t\\\"items\\\": [\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 1,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Bobby\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 19,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"louis@hardy.eg\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 13,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"cynthia@mills.mc\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 0,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"leo@graham.kp\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 2,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Maxine\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 14,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"miriam@horne.mo\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 20,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"danny@joyce.ro\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 25,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"christina@davenport.fo\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 3,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Ruth\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 1,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"heather@kirk.bm\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 29,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"kim@middleton.ve\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 2,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"harold@arthur.net\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 4,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Brandon\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 3,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"danny@parrott.eg\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 5,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"sarah@underwood.net\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 11,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"bonnie@banks.ye\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 5,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Kristina\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 18,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"frances@law.mf\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 15,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"nancy@o.mo\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 6,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"ben@holden.um\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 6,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"Keith\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"events\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 10,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"alfred@baldwin.za\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 9,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"courtney@hinson.us\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": 7,\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"email\\\": \\\"tracey@keller.li\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t}\\n\\t]\\n}\\n";
```

Convert it to proper json format by replaces spaces,line breaks etc.

```
String jsonStr = jsonString.replace("\\n", "").replace("\\t", "").replace("\\'", "").replace("\\", "");
```

And also replace

```
private static final String TAG_ITEM = "item";
```

with

```
private static final String TAG_ITEM = "items";
```